# Проблема с запуском видео на Android 7.1 - 9.0

Tags: android, videoview

У меня ошибка

> can't play this video на android 7.1 - 9.0

Но на Android новее такая ошибка не появляется. Почитал про кодировщик и расширения, но всё они начинаются с 3-4 Android и одинаковы.

Вот пример видео:

> https://kompot.ml/videos/17.mp4

Код:

```java
video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(jsonObject.getString("url")));
```

Comment: Вы проверяли все упомянутые версии Android на одном устройстве или на разных? Это видео имеет профиль High — далеко не любое устройство имеет его аппаратную поддержку, и Android тут обычно ни при чём

Comment: Я проверил на 8 разных устройствах. Так же app gallery проверили и поругались на эту ошибку. Не вижу в чём может быть проблема. Пробовал ffmpeg -i <input> -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart output.mp4, но не помогло.

Comment: Ваш ffmpeg сконвертировал видео в тот же самый профиль High, поэтому вполне логично, что не помогло. Конвертируйте в профиль Main

Comment: а можно пожалуйста этот конфиг, не могу его найти

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сработал этот конфиг:

```bash
ffmpeg -i <input> -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```